# How to grep this and NOT that?

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to return a file name from list.files, but there are 2 similarly named files.
`filename.csv
filename_review.csv`

I want to put each file name into its own list. Doing that for `filename_review.csv` is easy since it has unique stuff in it, but how do I sift out the other? I need to `grep(".csv", list.files())` without getting `filename_review.csv` returned.

Comment: Found this...
`fileListBig[!(fileListBig %in% fileListSmall)]`
and that works.

Comment: If what you discovered solved your problem, post it as an answer and then (after 2 days) accept it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found this... `fileListBig[!(fileListBig %in% fileListSmall)]` and that works.

Comment: There is no definition of `fileListBig` and `fileListSmall` in the question nor solution. The solution would be more useful for other people with similar questions if it were reproducible, as is the solution provided by @daroczig.

Answer (score 11):

Showing all files in the working directory that has a *csv* extension but not ends in *review* could be done:

```
setdiff(list.files(pattern='.csv$'), list.files(pattern='review.csv$'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to grep for what you *don't* want, and then return everything else.

```
csvs <- list.files(patt='.csv$')
csvs[!grepl('_', csvs)
```